# How do I inherit from class that calls base constructor?

Tags: c#, oop, xamarin, inheritance, specflow

So I've inherited this test platform for a Xamarin app for Android written in C# for Specflow.
I know nothing about Xamarin, very little about Specflow, and its been 10 years since I did any coding in C#, so bear with me..
Trying to create a class that inherits from Button, I get this error:

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'controlIdQuery' of 'Button.Button(Func <AppQuery, AppQuery>)'
```

My derived class looks like this:

```
public class Buttons : Button
{
}
```

Button class looks like this:

```
public class Button : ControlBase
{ 
    public Button(Func<AppQuery, AppQuery> controlIdQuery) : base(controlIdQuery) { }
}
```

And the parrent class, ControlBase of Button looks like this:

```
public abstract class ControlBase : AppBase
{
    public Func<AppQuery, AppQuery> controlIdQuery;

    public AppResult[] _appresult;
    public static IApp _appelement;
    public string _methodName;
    public object _argument;
    public bool waiting;
    public static Platform _appPlatform;

    public ControlBase(Func<AppQuery, AppQuery> idQuery)
    {
    }
}
```

I would expect to be able to create a class based on Button, as I can with the other control classes. What can I do to enable inheritance here?

Comment: A `Button` *is a* `ControlBase`. So when you create a new instance of `Button`, you basically "also" create an instance of `ControlBase`. To create an instance of `ControlBase`, an instance of `Func<AppQuery, AppQuery>` is necessary. So the constructor of `Button` takes that as a parameter and passes it through to the constructor of its `base` class. -- Now you want to inherit from `Button` which means, your new class *is a* `Button` and subsequently *is a* `ControlBase`. So your class also needs a constructor, that takes an instance of `Func<AppQuery, AppQuery>` and passes it through to base.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your class's constructor needs to call the base class constructor

```
public class Buttons : Button
{
   public Buttons(Func<AppQuery, AppQuery> controlIdQuery) : base(controlIdQuery) {}
}
```

Comment: Yes! Could you tell me why it has to be like this?

Comment: see @Corak's comment above, he explains it well

Comment: @PebermynteLars: C# provides classes with a default constructor that takes no parameters unless the class defines its own constructor(s).  That's why you see this sometimes work without a defined constructor.